Existence of a sub-vector space, stable by a nilpotent algebra over $\mathstrut{L(E)}$ with minimal dimensions.

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{C}$ -Vector space with a finite dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, and let $V$ be a nilpotent sub-algebra of $L(E)$.
Prove that there exists a non null sub-vector space $W$ of $E$, with minimal dimension, stable by all elements $f$ of $V$.

I assume the keyword here is the fact that $V$ is a nilpotent algebra, meaning that all elements $f$ of $V$ are nilpotent. My thought process started as this : "First, I'll see how I can build such stable sets, and then I'll find a way to make sure the minimality of its dimension". It is here where I got stuck, since I couldn't really build a set that is stable, not null, and has a minimal dimension at the same time.

I don't know abstract algebra well enough, but the Wikipedia definition states something seemingly stronger: an algebra is nilpotent if there is an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that any product of $n$ elements is $0$. This implies every element is nilpotent, but I would guess that the condition is far stronger (though I acknowledge that they could be equivalent, or even just equivalent in this case). Do you know which definition you're supposed to use?

Also, the minimality is a nothing restriction. If a non-trivial invariant subspace existed, then there would be a minimum dimension over the set of invariant subspaces. Basically, if you can show one exists, then one (or more) ones with minimal dimensions exist. And, given $E$ itself is automatically invariant and non-trivial, one of minimal dimension definitely does exist (with or without the nilpotent restriction). Are there other restrictions? Does the subspace need to be proper, for example?

Hello Theo! Thanks for commenting on my post. The only context that was given to me concerning the nilpotence of an algebra is the second definition that you've mentionned : "every element is nilpotent".
About your point on the minimality restriction, I feel like what you've said was true, but how can you prove that given a non-trivial subspace exists, there would be one with a minimal dimension?

Well, the set$${n \in \Bbb{N} : \text{there exists some subspace $W$ of dimension $n$, invariant under each $T \in V$}}$$is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{N}$, which is well-ordered. That is, non-empty subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ contain minima. If $n_0$ is the minimum of the above set, then by definition, there exists some subspace $W$ of (minimal) dimension $n_0$, invariant under each $T \in V$. QED.

Oh right, that makes so much sense! By the way, you can post your answer and I'll confirm its validity with the green check mark.

Given a non-trivial finite-dimensional vector space $E$, and any subset $V \subseteq L(E)$, not necessarily a nilpotent subalgebra (or indeed, a subalgebra at all), we can always find a subspace of minimal dimension that each $T \in V$ leaves invariant.
For the sake of brevity, let us say $W \le E$ means that $W$ is a subspace of $E$, and define
$$I_V := \{W \le E : \forall T \in V, \ T(W) \subseteq W\}.$$
That is, $I_V$ is the set of subspaces left invariant under every operator in $V$. Note that both the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ and the improper subspace $E$ are both contained in $I_V$, regardless of the contents of $V$.
Then, consider the set
$$\{\dim W : W \in I_V \setminus\{\{0\}\}\} \subseteq \Bbb{N}.$$
This subset of the natural numbers is non-empty and does not contain $0$, as it contains $\dim E \neq 0$, and only $\{0\}$ has dimension $0$. Since $\Bbb{N}$ is well-ordered, it must contain a minimum $n_0 = \dim W_0$, for some $W_0 \in I_V \setminus \{\{0\}\}$. This subspace $W_0$ is the one we want.
This particular trick of using the well-ordering of $\Bbb{N}$ is standard, and used throughout mathematics. It's used a lot in graph theory, for example, to ensure that paths or cycles can be taken to be of minimal length without loss of generality. It also pops up in abstract algebra, when proving fundamentals about free structures. It's also used in linear algebra when defining the minimal polynomial. And, of course, there will be many other uses, including in number theory itself!

I believe that we can also eschew the assumption that $E$ is finite-dimensional. Assuming the axiom of choice, (Hamel) bases still exist for every infinite-dimensional vector space. Each basis for a given space must still have the same cardinality, and so a (Hamel) dimension still exists, being the common cardinality of each basis. The cardinals are, based on the Von Neumann cardinal assignment, ordinal numbers, which are also well-ordered. As such, the same argument would work: there would be a subspace of minimal dimension, where the dimension could be some infinite ordinal.
That said, I'm not a set theorist, so take it with a grain of salt.

Perfectly reasoning! I admire your reasoning capabilities as a math student!
